# Line break in a description of facebook wall post

Tags: android, facebook

I really need to add a **line break** in a description of facebook wall post. There was a hack using `<center></center>` tags, but it does not work any more. I am using Facebook API for Android:

```
public Bundle createFacebookMsg() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    ...
    params.putString("description", "my custom string with LINE BREAKS");

    // does not work any more
    // params.putString("description", "line1<center></center>line2");

    ...
    return params;
}
```

Comment: They must disable it for a reason, but it's sure annoying. Now anyone that does find a way will hesitate to make it public!

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder(title).append('\n')
    .append('\n').append(message).append('\n').append('\n')
    .append(description);
// Message
postParams.putString("message", messageData.toString());
```